# Сортировка JSONObject по ключу дате Java, алгоритм

Tags: java, алгоритм, json

Использую JSONSimple.
Имею такой `Json`:

```
{
  "2017-05-19": [{"time": "time"}],
  "2017-05-18": [{"time": "time"}],
  "2017-05-17": [{"time": "time"}],
  "2017-05-16": [{"time": "time"}],
  "2017-05-01": [{"time": "time"}],
  "2017-05-05": [{"time": "time"}],
  "2017-05-10": [{"time": "time"}],
  "2017-06-18": [{"time": "time"}],
  "2017-06-29": [{"time": "time"}],
  "2017-06-16": [{"time": "time"}],
  "2017-06-01": [{"time": "time"}],
  "2017-06-06": [{"time": "time"}],
  "2017-06-15": [{"time": "time"}]
}
```

Подскажите варианты сортировки такого объекта по ключу - дате. Что бы всё было в нормальном порядке, как должно быть.

**UPD**. Попробовал сделать так:

```
Map<Date, JSONArray> treeMap = new TreeMap<Date, JSONArray>(data);

JSONObject test = new JSONObject(treeMap);
```

не отсортировал.

```
JSONObject data = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(new FileReader(request.getServletContext().getRealPath("")+ File.separator+"temp.json"));

                    List<UserRow> list = new ArrayList<>();

                    for(Object o: data.keySet()) {
                        list.add(new UserRow(o.toString(), (JSONArray) data.get(o)));
                    }

                    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<UserRow>() {
                        @Override
                        public int compare(UserRow o1, UserRow o2) {
                            return o1.getDate().compareTo(o2.getDate());
                        }
                    });

                    JSONObject nData = new JSONObject();

                    for(UserRow u: list) {
                        nData.put(u.dateToString(), u.getTimes());
                    }

                    System.out.println(nData.toString());
```

Класс UserRow:

```
public class UserRow {

    private Date date;
    private JSONArray times;

    private SimpleDateFormat fdate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    public UserRow(String date, JSONArray times) throws ParseException {
        this.date = fdate.parse(date);
        this.times = times;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public JSONArray getTimes() {
        return times;
    }

    public String dateToString() {
        return fdate.format(getDate());
    }
}
```

Comment: HashMap<Date,JSONArray> не?

Comment: @rjhdby в реализации JSONSimple то и есть HashMap. Но HashMap не сортирует.

Comment: Так кастомный компаратор же

Comment: JSONObject гарантирует, что элементы будут идти в порядке добавления?

Comment: @rjhdby хоть 10 кастомных компараторов, JSONObject использует Ваш HeashMap только для того, чтобы взять из него объекты и переложить в свой, у которого нет никаких компараторов. Как ни сортируйте, он пересортирует по-своему

Comment: @Sergey еще раз. Помещаем всю эту радость в собственную коллекцию и сортируем как левой пятке захочется

Comment: @rjhdby Но вопрос-то в том как отсортировать JSONObject

Comment: @Sergey когда тебя спрашивают, как молотком закрутить шуруп, то гораздо корректнее будет посоветовать воспользоваться отверткой

Comment: @Sergey наоборот. мне отсылают данные отсрортированные уже. А приходят не в отсортированном виде.

Comment: @rjhdby у JSONObject своя сортировка. Я попробовал сделать как ниже человек подсказал - у JSONObject-а всё по своему.

Comment: Тьфу блин. Вам нужно, чтобы в JSON ключи по порядку были, а не в принципе распарсенные данные в нужном порядке отображать? Если так, то мое решение действительно не подойдет. Да и вообще в реальном софте никто не надеется на порядок данных в JSON. Обе стороны (и отправитель данных и получатель) должны знать, в каком порядке сортировать данные, чтобы отображать, а сам JSON может быть перемешан как угодно.

Comment: @rjhdby Шурупы отлично заколачиваются молотком. И кто с советами под руку лезет тоже:)

Comment: @Sergey вопрос был про закручивание, а не про заколачивание, так что не лезьте с советами

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю распарсить такой Json не проблема, поэтому будем считать, что данные в строковом виде есть.

Каждую дату парсим с помощью `SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")` в объект `Date`. Время парсим так, как требуется по заданию.

Загоняем пары дата-время в `List` из структур, типа:

```
class MyDate {
    Date date;
    Time time; //Здесь тип `Time` - псевдотип. Реальный тип поля зависит от того, как Вы парсите время
}
```

Далее, как вариант, используем метод `Collections.sort(List, Comparator)`. Где `List` - это наша коллекция, а `Comparator` - это реализация соответствующего интерфейса, в методе `compareTo` которого всего одна строка: `return date1.compareTo(date2)`.

После этого список наших структур `MyDate` отсортирован по возрастанию `Date`.

Comment: там не время, а массив объктов. Тобишь в Массиве будут объекты `{}`.

Comment: Поэтому я и написал, что время - это Ваш формат :) Там может быть тип `List<Time>` например. Это не важно. Важно, что мы работаем с полем `Date`, как признаком для сортировки.

Comment: так? добавил в шапку

Comment: Еще бы добавить, где формируете List. Вы уверены, что после этой операции, пробежав циклом по датам, они не выведутся в нужном порядке? Мы не json сортируем, а List<UserRow>.

Comment: добавил в шапку